# How to make a C++ Application in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, exe, sfml

I made a small C++ game in Visual Studio 2015 using the SFML library and it works perfectly fine when I click the '► Local Windows Debugger' button in 'Debug-x86' mode.

My game does not work on anyone else computer because it says the next dll files are missing:

> msvcp140.dll
>   msvcp140d.dll
>   vcruntime140d.dll
>   ucrtbased.dll
>   appcrt140d.dll
>   desktopcrt140d.dll

I know those files comes from the Visual Studio 2015 Instalation, but for those who do not have VS installed what can I do to fix those problems?

I copied the first 4 dll from my PC C:\Windows\System32 *(msvcp140.dll, msvcp140d.dll, vcruntime140d.dll, ucrtbased.dll)* on the exe path but couldn't find the last 2 in nowhere. *(appcrt140d.dll, desktopcrt140d.dll)*

I have no idea how to make an exe aplication with all its dll dependencies.

When I use the 'Release-x86' mode it throws the next error by the way.

> Exception thrown at 0x62234AE7 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Timber.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

Comment: If you have dependencies and if they are not provided by OS, then you have to supply them.

Comment: You need to distribute the Visual Studio C++ Redistributable. [Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=48145). Note that only the release DLLs are included in the redistributable.

Comment: Your Release-x86 configuration looks inconsistent. Check linker input settings, and make sure no debug versions of any libs are referenced.

Comment: `msvcp140d.dll` is a debug dll that is part of the CRT. It is not redistributable. Besides violating the Visual Studio licence your program should never require both debug and release dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by configuring the release mode of the SFML library in the project's properties and by switching to 'Release-x86' mode instead of 'Debug-x86'.

You can read more about how to configure your SFML projects here: https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php